# how do i change scriptresource.axd target?

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, scriptresource.axd

I changed one javascript file for infragistics controls in the below folder.

C:\Program Files\Infragistics\NetAdvantage 2010.3\ASP.NET\CLR3.5\Scripts

but when I am using the control , still refering to the old one? so i am not getting the updated javascript, how do i change the target for axd??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is an EnableEmbededJavaScript property that you can set to change this behavior:
http://help.infragistics.com/NetAdvantage/ASPNET/Current/CLR3.5/?page=Infragistics4.Web.v11.2~Infragistics.Web.UI.Framework.Data.FlatDataBoundControl~EnableEmbeddedJavaScript.html

After setting this to false you will need to use the ScriptManager on the page to load your modified JavaScript.